# Folder structure and apt-get purge

Tags: 14.04, apt, purge

I have installed nginx on a new ubuntu server with the following command:

```
apt-get install nginx
```

I removed nginx with the following commands:

```
apt-get purge nginx
apt-get autoremove
```

How come the nginx folder is not removed from the system? In other words, I still find the nginx folder with nginx files here:

```
/etc/nginx
```

How do I completely remove all nginx-related files and folders from the system when uninstalling nginx?

**EDIT:**

When I run find/etc/nginx, I see the following:

```
/etc/nginx
/etc/nginx/win-utf
/etc/nginx/proxy_params
/etc/nginx/fastcgi_params
/etc/nginx/nginx.config
/etc/nginx/koi-win
/etc/nginx/sites-available
/etc/nginx/sites-available/default
/etc/nginx/koi-utf
/etc/nginx/naxsi.rules
/etc/nginx/scgi_params
/etc/nginx/naxsi_core.rules
/etc/nginx/uwsgi_params
/etc/nginx/naxsi-ui.conf.1.4.1
/etc/nginx/sites-enabled
/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default
/etc/nginx/mime.types
```

Comment: What's in it? Run `find /etc/nginx` and [edit] your question to include the contents please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look with `dpkg -S <filename>`, you'll see that these files actually came from a package called `nginx-common`. This is installed at the same time as the base `nginx` package. Many packages are split up like this.

When you purge something, only the *specified* packages are purged. If things need to be removed to satisfy dependencies (which *may* be the case here), they will just be removed, not purged. It may be the case that `nginx-common` is still installed.

Either which way, the solution is the same. Purge `nginx-common`:

```
sudo apt-get purge nginx-common
```

---

In other cases where you have remnant `/etc/` files after a purge, this is often down to files that didn't exist at install-time. In your case they all looked like packaged files but in many cases there could be a user-created file sitting in there that they might want to rescue before manually deleting.

Apt will *never* remove these, even with `purge`. If you're sure you want to delete them, `sudo rm -rf /etc/nginx` will do the trick, but again, be very careful.